# Dragging UIImageView into UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, interface-builder

I am working on an app, I have a rootViewController relationship between the navigation controller and the dashboard controller. I can't drag a normal UIView, or UIImageView into the controller anymore in Interface Builder, what am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot of Interface Builder]

Comment: Does your storyboard zoom level remains same as in screenshot, when you drag the UIView ?

Comment: I already zoomed in, I made this screenshot for demonstration purposes. I drag a UIImageView into the controller (which is a UIViewController, with RootViewController relationship).

Comment: UIImageView can be dragged on UIView. You need to have UIView in place then UIImageView can be placed on it

Comment: Have you tried to delete and drag into a new viewController? It looks like your dashboard controller don't have a basic UIView